# May I know the Login IP ranges to access salesforce event log file browser?

Tags: file, browser, salesforce, event-log

getting this error , Oauth2 failed.Invalid credentials. its due to IP restriction. plaese share IP ranges for salesforce ELF browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install the app from the Connected Apps OAuth Usage page and then set the IP Relaxation settings to "relax all restrictions" for this app? Worked for me.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_continuous_ip.htm&type=5

Answer (score -1):

IP login ranges are set *per Salesforce org* and optionally *per Profile*. They are not universal and have nothing in particular to do with the Event Log File browser.

You need to speak with your local Salesforce administrator for information about the configuration of your org.

---

My initial answer (above) did not reflect awareness that "event log file browser" refers to a third-party Heroku application. It would be helpful to be specific in the question.

Heroku applications in general do not have static IPs or fixed IP ranges at all, so there's no way for you to include this application's IP in an allow list. In order to make that possible, you would need to host your own instance of this application (assuming it is open source) in a Heroku Private Space, which does have specific assigned IPs for network egress, and then allow-list the IPs of that Private Space. Note that Private Spaces come at a substantial additional cost.

Comment: I think the issues is that the you need to know the IP address hosting https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/ if your org only allows administrators to login from specific address ranges.  The issues has also been noted on the project's repo. https://github.com/abisek/salesforce-elf-browser/issues/53  Our company had this setup but it broke when the service changed IPs.   Writing a custom tool seems to be the only option here.

Comment: I was not aware that this question was referring to a third-party product. I will update my answer to reflect the fact that this is a Heroku application.